# recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

I am working on vmaware with ubuntu 16.04 
I want to add system call to kernel like "hello world".
So i downloaded a latest kernel, i have done some changes regarding to system call ,when i compile kernel i get this error.

Error in terminal while compiling

> ld: cannot find opsyscall/built-in.o: No such file or directory
>
> Makefile:969: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
>
> make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1

kernel's Makefile line 968 and 969 is

> vmlinux: scripts/link-vmlinux.sh vmlinux_prereq $(vmlinux-deps) FORCE
>
> +$(call if_changed,link-vmlinux)

In opsyscall folder i have a Makefile

make file content :

> obj-y : syscall.o

i have done all the changes that needed for a system call.

Comment: this is my c code in opsyscall directory
 #include < linux/kernel.h>

 #include < linux/syscalls.h>

asmlinkage long sys_opsyscall(const char *test)

{

  printk(KERN_ALERT "My Call : %s\n",test);

 return 0;
}

Comment: Add this code **into the question post**.